# How to Display the feed in index visitor page in PHPfox

Tags: php, phpfox

I am trying to display the user feed on index visitor page. But I can't, so please any one can help me to do that. And also tell me which function was displaying this feed.

Comment: Please show the code you have already tried. In your question, you refer to "which function" and "this feed". You definitely has omitted some of the context.

Comment: hi YakovL thanks for your reply. the code was too long how can i share please tell me.

Comment: You can use http://pastebin.com/, for instance. It has syntax highlighting, too.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/n3D7zymK

Comment: i have shared the code in pastebin.com in above link please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to get feed on **View Page**

```
<div class="feed-wrapper">{module name='feed.display'}</div>
```

for further modification you can filter the feed and comment module.